# Logic for choosing a certificate chain during a “server-hello” message in a SSL/TLS handshake?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

In a client-server ssl handshake, my server sends a certificate chain back to the client in a server-hello message. But I want to understand as to how that particular certificate chain is getting selected.

My keystore has 5 chains

```
chain1>
privatekey (expired at let's say date1) --
intermediate or server cert (valid) --
root (valid)

chain2>
privatekey cert (valid for 6 more months)--
intermediate or server cert (valid)--
root (valid)

chain3>
privatekey cert (expired at lets say date2) --
intermediate or server cert (valid)--
root (valid)

chain4>
privatekey cert (valid for 1 year) --
intermediate or server cert (valid)--
root (valid)

chain5>
privatekey cert (expired at lets say date3) --
intermediate or server cert (valid)--
root (valid)
```

Now whenever a client tries to connect to my server (for a webservice) the below exception is being obtained and the client is not able to connect

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation
>   failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check
>   failed. .................. *more lines*.. caused by
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check
>   failed........ *more lines*.. caused by
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: NotAfter : date1

Tried reconnecting but again the same error with date2 this time. Now this was not happening earlier even when there were expired certs in my keystore.

Can anyone explain as to how the certificate chain gets selected in the server hello message? I tried researching a lot but couldn't get something concrete

Comment: That's impossible to answer without knowing how you set up your ServerSocket.

Comment: @Lothar : ServerSocket, X509TrustManager or any other advanced factories are not customised.

Comment: X509TrustManagers are used to check the peer's certificate and have nothing to do with the selection of the own certificate during the handshake. Again, please provide the source where you set up your ServerSocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 'impossible to answer', contrary to what you've been told in comments.

1. A certificate is chosen which satisfies the signers, cipher suites, and protocols supplied by the client in the `ClientHello` message.
2. If there is a choice, if you've installed a `KeyManager`, that's in control: otherwise, JSSE is in control and it isn't further specified.

Comment: I am quite sure JSSE is in control in this case since I don't remember any KeyManager. checked rfc5246 official documentation but it's a lot of permutations and combinations of cipher suites and algos which is difficult to decipher.. atleast for me

Comment: @vistar81 Not sure what you're expecting me to say to that, but it's hard to see why you don't just get rid of the expired certificates.

Comment: There is a little information about the key selection algorithm at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509ExtendedKeyManager. It vaguely tells that the selection is based on the cipher suites supported by server and client, SNI (server name indication) and acceptable issuers. Judging from the OPs experience the key selection algorithm is random otherwise.